# mybatis create/update database on application startup?

Tags: configuration, mybatis

Is present some configuration properties for mybatis in order to create/update database on application startup like does "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" ?

Answer (score 1):

Well,  The [MyBatis Migration Tool](http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/wiki/Migration) might meet your needs, it sounds a little different than Hibernate though.